# How to set shortcut Key to a paragraph style (InDesign jsx Script)?

Tags: javascript, scripting, jsx, adobe-indesign

I'm writting a script for InDesign which creates some paragraph styles, I need to set a shortcut key in the moment of paragraph style creation. Is it possible?

```
myDoc.paragraphStyles.add({
  name: "BODY TEXT",
  appliedFont: "Geon",
  fontStyle: "Regular",
  balanceRaggedLines: true,
  capitalization: Capitalization.ALL_CAPS,
  hyphenation: false,
  justification: Justification.LEFT_ALIGN,
  pointSize: 13,
  leading: 13 * 1.2,
  tracking: 70,
  fillColor: "Paper",})
```

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6gJQ.png)

Comment: This guy probably managed to do it: https://youtu.be/Jt2GX4EMJ5k and https://youtu.be/QVLHpsbDK9Q I've no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows user shortcuts stored in files `*.indk` in folder `$USERPROFILE$\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\InDesign\Version 8.0\en_GB\InDesign Shortcut Sets\` (there can be another version, of course)

They are XML files with quite obvious structure. Perhaps you could try to change a content of the file (or create the file if it's doesn't exist) with script.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, but it would work only localy. My intention is to distribute the final JSX to coworkers install on their computers.

Comment: It could work if coworkers don't mind to enable your set of shortcuts via menu (Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts > Set). Or if they already have their sets you could find and update them, I think.